# setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key Using UICollectionView

Tags: objective-c, uicollectionview

I have a UICollectionView populated with cells that has a custom class, every cell has 3 labels an image and I just added a button, Before adding the button Everything was working fine, now that I added the button and connected it to the custom cell class (where I connected also the labels and image) The app crashes when populating the UICollectionView.
On the connection inspectors the button has only the Outlet that connects him to the custom cell class (like the other elements) so Why does the app crashes?
This is my header file:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>


@interface CollectionViewCell : UICollectionViewCell
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *TestButton; //this one is the button that causes the crash
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *titleP;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *price;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *codeP;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *img;

@end
```

EDIT:
I don't know what happend with the StoryBoard but I just had to clean the project and everything worked fine, thanks all for the help.

Comment: Show the whole error message.

Comment: And the key. And the code. And really *T*estButton or *t*estButton?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Usually when I get this error it is because I renamed an outlet in code but didn't update the storyboard correctly. If you select your storyboard and the connections inspector you will likely see one of the connects with a ! that should be your offender.

I hope that helps.

[image]

Comment: I just had to clean the Project, don't know why but It worked

Answer (score 0):

In my experience this happens:

1. I have renamed an IBOutlet/IBAction without using the `refactor` when [right clicking on the name of the variable/function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HuXha.png)
2. I have removed the IBOutlet/IBAction from the code with out removing the connection from the [connection inspector](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U5C5D.png).

So make sure to check the connection inspector for a [yellow triangle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5pAsQ.png)  for a renamed/removed variable or function.

Answer (score 0):

If IBOutlet connections are right, try going to Identity Inspector, make sure that "Module" is set (no matter by selecting "Inherit Module From Target" or by manual input).

This fixed the error in my case.